# NULL comparison in SQL server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I know that in SQL when we compare two NULL values, result is always false. Hence, statements like

```
SELECT case when NULL = NULL then '1' else '0' end
```

will always print '0'. My question is how functions like `ISNULL` determine whether value is null or not. Because, as per my understanding (and explained in above query) comparison of two null values is always FALSE.

Comment: Are you trying to find a way to make your statement work (which the existing answers are addressing), or are you literally asking how the `ISNULL` function in SQL Server itself works?

Comment: No, `NULL = NULL` returns `UNKNOWN`, not `FALSE`. Try `SELECT case when NOT (NULL = NULL) then '1' else '0' end` which also returns 0. And what makes you think that *built in* functions are implemented in SQL?

Comment: @AdrianWragg: Actually I am asking for the second. How `ISNULL` function in SQL server works. If comparison of two nulls is not defined/unknown then how `isnull` function compares two null values to return appropriate results?

Comment: Thought so; I believe the existing answers have missed that. Easy answer - it's built into the database itself. As @Damien_The_Unbeliever says, it's probably not using SQL itself (for performance) so completely avoids the issue you see.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Sorry, if I misquoted the question. I know that comparison of two null values will return undefined result. My question is what logic is applied in functions like `isnull` to compare two null values and return results appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial assumption appears to be that `ISNULL` is an alias for existing functionality which can be implemented directly within SQL statements, in the same way that a SQL function can. You are then asking how that function works.

This is an incorrect starting point, hence the confusion. Instead, like similar commands such as `IN` and `LIKE`, `ISNULL` is parsed and run within the database engine itself; its actual implementation is most likely written in C.

If you **really** want to look into the details of the implementation, you could take a look instead at mySQL - it's open source, so you may be able to search through the code to see how ISNULL is implemented there. They even provide a [guided tour](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/guided-tour.html) of the code if required.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the `set ansi_nulls off` and then check your result. Null can be thought of as an unknown value and when you are comparing two unknown values then you will get the result as false only. The comparisons null = null is undefined.

```
set ansi_nulls off
SELECT case when NULL = NULL then '1' else '0' end
```

Result:-

```
1
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx)

> When SET ANSI_NULLS is OFF, the Equals (=) and Not Equal To (<>)
>   comparison operators do not follow the ISO standard. A SELECT
>   statement that uses WHERE column_name = NULL returns the rows that
>   have null values in column_name. A SELECT statement that uses WHERE
>   column_name <> NULL returns the rows that have nonnull values in the
>   column. Also, a SELECT statement that uses WHERE column_name <>
>   XYZ_value returns all rows that are not XYZ_value and that are not
>   NULL.

As correctly pointed by Damien in comments the behavior of NULL = NULL is **unknown or undefined.**

Comment: Yes. I know use of ansi_nulls. But my question is more around how isnull function treats the null values. From the explanation above, it looks like inside isnull function also, we compare values using ansi_nulls off. Correct me if wrong.

Comment: @AshutoshPujari:- as I said consider it as unknown values so when you compare two unknown values then it is always false when the set_ansi is set to ON

Comment: No, `NULL = NULL` evaluates to `UNKNOWN`, not `FALSE`. If you negate the expression, it's still not `true`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever:- Do correct me if i am wrong but I have written in my answer that `The comparisons null = null is undefined` so does that not take it into account?

Comment: @R.T. - you say "hence evaluates to false" but that's not so. `NOT (NULL = NULL)` still isn't true.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever:- Removed the misleading part. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> ... or {2} are you literally asking how the ISNULL function in SQL
>   Server itself works?
>
> Actually I am asking for the second{2}. How ISNULL function in SQL server
>   works. If comparison of two nulls is not defined/unknown then how
>   isnull function compares two null values to return appropriate
>   results?

Null is a special marker used in Structured Query Language (SQL) to indicate **that a data value does not exist** in the database. ... [NULL (SQL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL))

[ISNULL ( check_expression , replacement_value )](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) is not concerned with *comparison of* values at all. It is concerned purely with `the existence of value` in the first parameter.

It tests if the `check_expression` has any value. If it does have any value that value is returned. If `check_expression` has no value the ISNULL function returns the second parameter `replacement_value`.

It does NOT compare the two values. It tests for`the existence of value` in the first parameter only.

Answer (score 0):

```
set ansi_nulls off

SELECT case when NULL = NULL then '1' else '0' end

result=1

set ansi_nulls on
SELECT case when NULL = NULL then '1' else '0' end

result=0


so that is the difference
```

Comment: And how it is different to my answer without even providing any explanation?

Answer (score 0):

I hope it works

SELECT CASE WHEN ISNULL(NULL,NULL) = NULL THEN  1 ELSE 0 END

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT case when  'NULL' = 'NULL' then '1' else '0' end


SELECT case when   isnull(columnname,'NULL')='NULL' then '1' else '0' end



SET ANSI_NULLS OFF 

SELECT case when NULL = NULL then '1' else '0' end
```

Comment: 'NULL' is not the same as NULL